# Why the printing result is not matched with the actual stuff

Tags: wpf, printing, xps

My application is based on WPF, and it can create plot then print. The issue is: sometimes the printed result is not matched with what it looks in the application (see below image for the bar legend).

**Note**: 
- The problem only occurs when the driver of the printer is **not** XPS driver. If I print it using a XPS driver on the same printer, then everything works fine.

Can anybody shed some light on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, this should be an issue for Microsoft, there is problem when printing the XPS file